# Random number in script

Tags: javascript, random, jwplayer

I would like to put a number to link to different music style playlist. To a specific music style is no problem.

But also i want to make a random video player with all music playlists
Is there a way to put a random number between 1-10 on the place --randomnumber--

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
      'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player-licensed.swf',
      'id': 'playerID',
      'width': '650',
      'height': '370',
      'playlistfile': 'jwplayer/--randomnumber--/playlist.xml',
      'controlbar': 'over',
      'autostart': 'true',
      'repeat': 'always'    
      })  
 </script>
```

Thank you already for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could quickly define a function to generate a random integer, as follows:

```
function generateRandomInteger(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}
```

Then concatenate that into your `playlistfile` property in your existing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
      'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player-licensed.swf',
      'id': 'playerID',
      'width': '650',
      'height': '370',
      'playlistfile': 'jwplayer/' + generateRandomInteger(10) + '/playlist.xml',
      'controlbar': 'over',
      'autostart': 'true',
      'repeat': 'always'    
      })  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`'jwplayer/' + Math.ceil(10 * Math.random()) + '/playlist.xml'`